# Usage of 'morbid' and 'morbidity' in non-medical contexts

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I have a question about the liberty we can take in using the word 'morbid'.

Generally speaking, what I understand the word to mean in a medical context is a state of sickliness. That's just how the population is and life goes on.

I have the following example wherein I used the word morbid in a non-medical context:

> Last Christmas, the family woke-up to the sound of loud arguments coming from Jim and Jane's room. We all just stayed in bed till it was time to get the lunch ready for the family. Having lost the entire morning, I decided to just order pizzas for the day. Jim and Jane seemingly didn't find any resolution to their fight and their bad mood affected all of us. It was disappointing to spend the Christmas lunch and dinner with a sense of morbidity in the air. Forgive me for not wanting that to happen this year.

Interested to know your views. I actually find it interesting to use words in ways inspired from different topics altogether. I feel it can be quite impactful without being obvious.

Comment: In that context, "morbidity" makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: The everyday use of [**morbid**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/morbid) is: Characterized by an abnormal and unhealthy interest in disturbing and unpleasant subjects, especially death and disease. **Morbidity** is medical in usage and works even less well. I suggest "...with a sense of [**hostility**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hostility) in the air."

Comment: I did think about alternatives such a 'hostility'. But, you see, with 'morbidity', I feel there is a sense of acceptance or resignation. I feel with 'hostility', there seems to be a deliberately confrontational environment. Here, even Jim and Jane seem to have accepted that Christmas is ruined.  Life just goes on. Many poorer populations just accept their (medical) conditions as part of their day to day life. They very well know their potential is limited because of this and that they don't have the resources to fix it and they also can't make it obvious.

Comment: And then you also have your plain govt. stats about the morbidity of these populations. Thanks for your perspectives! Of course, I'm no writer and there are perhaps better 'artistic' ways to phrase the example that I used, with the same word.

Comment: Perhaps then you need ***disharmony***, *defeat*, *resignation* or one of their synonyms.

Comment: Honest opinion: *morbidity* just does not work in your context-  at all.

Answer (score 1):

Even coming from a medical background in childhood, I am nevertheless accustomed to this use of *morbid* and *morbidity*, despite the medical use or the connotations of death.

> morbid =
>
> abnormally susceptible to or characterized by gloomy or unwholesome feelings
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morbid)

to be gloomy on Christmas day is indeed abnormal relative to most people's expectations of the festival. I believe your usage to be justified.

Comment: 'Morbid' is used far more often in the 'characterised by gloomy/unwholesome feelings' sense than 'morbidity' is in the related sense. The first 50 hits in a Google search for 'morbidity' referred to the medical sense either first in listed dictionary definitions or in real-world examples. I'd say 'morbidness' is the more usual choice of noun for the non-medical sense. I'd also say that the default 'everyday' usage of _morbid_ is more in line with the Lexico definition [1] (as given by @Weather Vane above)  rather than denoting just a 'gloomy' atmosphere..

Comment: Oh, actually I didn't find that specific meaning. Thanks for that! I found mostly only examples in medical contexts.

Comment: You didn't investigate Merriam-Webster far enough.  See this link https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morbidness#other-words - it refers to "morbidness"

Answer (score 0):

**morbidness**

> Well, I am still alive, no sense dwelling on the morbidness of it
> all.
>
> https://www.lexico.com/definition/morbidness

Merriam-Webster also attests this:

> Other Words from morbid
>
> morbidly adverb
>
> morbidness noun
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/morbidness#other-words